# Entity Framework Core 1.0.1 add-migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Since EF Core migrated to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` (instead of `EntityFramework.*`), it seems that the recommended command line to add db migrations is back to `add-migration` from package manager.

[ef core add migration documentation](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-your-database)

However it seems there isn't a package anymore for commands and that the package installation of v 1.0.1 doesn't add any command.

The error message I'm getting when running `Add-Migration` is

> Cannot execute this command because EntityFramework.Commands is not installed in the startup project 'project name'.

Did I miss something? Is there a new way to add the commands or so? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't go through package manager to achieve this, but through standard cmd

Comment: The doc instructs to use the package manager console and when I use standard command line (ps / cmder) the cmdlet is not being recognized

Comment: Based on standard cmd, you should do 'dotnet migrations add MigrationName' to make it works (be sure to do it within the folder where you DbContext and your objects are located)

Comment: this is what I was used to do before they moved to dot net standard about a month ago, now when I do that I get `No executable found matching command "dotnet-migrations"`  
I think I'm missing the migration command in my project.json and/or the commands package but both are nowhere to be found and the doc instructs to use the PS cmdlets like in .net classic

Comment: Sorry, dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName. You should have package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' installed in your project.json also, into the tools section

Comment: oh ok they moved commands to tools, thanks! And this package doesn't seem to have been updated for netstandard1.6 monikers yet, I'll try to play around with dependencies and get back at you with my results

Comment: got the command to work adding `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"` under tools sections and `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final"` under dependencies of the web app project.  
However my dbcontext is in a library project and the command can't seem to find it.

Comment: @baywet: Read the documentation about this limitation and the workaround for it https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, I had seen that page for commands details but not these workarounds. Workaround 1 did the trick for me, only thing is because this is an app now, instellisense cannot find the types in referencing apps. I'll just do that when I need to add/update migrations.
Would you mind adding what you helped me with as an answer so you can get the credit you deserve? I'll also add the points I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use the Package Manager Console commands (e.g. `Add-Migration`) on .NET Core projects, your `project.json` will need to look something like this.

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
            "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
            "type": "build"
        }
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
}
```

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` under `dependencies` ensures the PowerShell commands get registered. It's `"type": "build"` ensures they don't get published with your application. The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` under `dependencies` ensures the `dotnet ef` command gets registered (which is called by the PowerShell commands).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was about to condensate my comment to have it here. I also had to use the workaround from the doc as pointed out per @tseng I'll do it if he doesn't